# opencv: how to find contours in a single depth image?

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision

I'm getting the following error when trying to find contours in a single depth image. I already have a single depth img, I believe I don't need to use `cv.cvtcolor`.

```
img = np.random.rand(224,224)
img.astype('uint8')
threshold_value = int(np.max(img) * 0.2)
print(threshold_value)
_, img = cv.threshold(img, threshold_value, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
_, contours, _ = cv.findContours(img,
                                    cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

**error:**

> FindContours supports only CV_8UC1 images when mode !=
>   CV_RETR_FLOODFILL otherwise supports CV_32SC1 images only in function
>   'cvStartFindContours_Impl'

Comment: How did you read it? What does single depth mean? You likely do not have 1-bit (binary) image or 8-bit, single channel image. Best to convert to grayscale or read it in as grayscale. Check the shape of your input image (img.shape)

Comment: Please show your read command and the results of img.shape and img.depth

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.

Comment: Please don't forget to upvote all working answers, and accept the one you like the most. Probably you know this, but this is to let the community know which answers were useful and to reward the people for their time and effort as well ;) See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
img.astype('uint8')
```

does nothing. you should assign the result to something, like:

```
img = img.astype('uint8')
```

then you won't get the error you described.

but the results still won't be as you might expect, because `np.random.rand()` assigns values in range (0..1) and by converting them to `uint8` everything becomes zero. might want to fix that part as well.

Answer (score 0):

8UC1 means 8bit pixels, therefore try using the converting image into grayscale.

Comment: gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) converts only rgb image to grayscale but not single depth img

Comment: `@Umair Javaid` Your image is likely not 8-bits, but was read in as 24-bits or 1-bit, as I said above in my earlier comment. Check img.shape and img.depth to see what they tell you.

Answer (score 0):

You should first convert values so that the values are up to 255. Then, you should transform the type. Something like this:

```
img = np.random.rand(224,224)
# Take values from 0-1 to 0-255
img *= 255
# Convert type
img = img.astype('uint8')
(...)
```